# Have I implemented Milstein's method/Euler-Maruyama correctly?

Tags: python, numerical-methods, differential-equations, stochastic

I have an stochastic differential equation (SDE) that I am trying to solve using Milsteins method but am getting results that disagree with experiment.

The SDE is

[image]

which I have broken up into 2 first order equations:

eq1:  [image]

eq2:  [image]

Then I have used the Ito form:

[image]

So that for eq1:

[image]

and for eq2:

[image]

My python code used to attempt to solve this is like so:

```
# set constants from real data
Gamma0 = 4000  # defines enviromental damping
Omega0 = 75e3*2*np.pi # defines the angular frequency of the motion
eta = 0 # set eta 0 => no effect from non-linear p*q**2 term
T_0 = 300 # temperature of enviroment
k_b = scipy.constants.Boltzmann 
m = 3.1e-19 # mass of oscillator

# set a and b functions for these 2 equations
def a_p(t, p, q):
    return -(Gamma0 - Omega0*eta*q**2)*p

def b_p(t, p, q):
    return np.sqrt(2*Gamma0*k_b*T_0/m)

def a_q(t, p, q):
    return p

# generate time data
dt = 10e-11
tArray = np.arange(0, 200e-6, dt)

# initialise q and p arrays and set initial conditions to 0, 0
q0 = 0
p0 = 0
q = np.zeros_like(tArray)
p = np.zeros_like(tArray)
q[0] = q0
p[0] = p0

# generate normally distributed random numbers
dwArray = np.random.normal(0, np.sqrt(dt), len(tArray)) # independent and identically distributed normal random variables with expected value 0 and variance dt

# iterate through implementing Milstein's method (technically Euler-Maruyama since b' = 0
for n, t in enumerate(tArray[:-1]):
    dw = dwArray[n]
    p[n+1] = p[n] + a_p(t, p[n], q[n])*dt + b_p(t, p[n], q[n])*dw + 0
    q[n+1] = q[n] + a_q(t, p[n], q[n])*dt + 0
```

Where in this case p is velocity and q is position.

I then get the following plots of q and p:

[image: p plotted with time]

[image: q plotted with time]

I expected the resulting plot of position to look something like the following, which I get from experimental data (from which the constants used in the model are determined):

[image: experimental position with time]

Have I implemented Milstein's method correctly?

If I have, what else might be wrong my process of solving the SDE that'd causing this disagreement with the experiment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed a term in the drift coefficient, note that to the right of `dp` there are two `dt` terms. Thus

```
def a_p(t, p, q):
    return -(Gamma0 - Omega0*eta*q**2)*p - Omega0**2*q
```

which is actually the part that makes the oscillator into an oscillator. With that corrected the solution looks like

[image: One possible solution]

And no, you did not implement the Milstein method as there are no derivatives of `b_p` which are what distinguishes Milstein from Euler-Maruyama, the missing term is `+0.5*b'(X)*b(X)*(dW**2-dt)`.

---

There is also a derivative-free version of Milsteins method as a two-stage kind-of Runge-Kutta method, documented in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_method_%28SDE%29) or the original in [arxiv.org (PDF)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.0933.pdf).

The step there is (vector based, duplicate into `X=[p,q]`, `K1=[k1_p,k1_q]` etc. to be close to your conventions)

```
S = random_choice_of ([-1,1])
K1 = a(X )*dt + b(X )*(dW - S*sqrt(dt))
Xh = X + K1
K2 = a(Xh)*dt + b(Xh)*(dW + S*sqrt(dt))

X = X + 0.5 * (K1+K2)
```

Comment: What a great eye.  Outstanding answer.

Comment: @duffymo : Thanks. I (re-)typed the original order 1 formulation in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2339579/115115, so already has some insight.

Comment: I've voted that up as well.  Great use of LaTex - beautiful.  Does SO allow it natively now, or did you create images?

Comment: @duffymo : No, no math support on SO, the images are from the rendered formulas in math.SE.

Comment: brilliant, thanks, can't believe I missed that. I used http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php to generate the html for the latex equations which can then be used on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann I have a doubt, I was under the impression that for multivariable systems d**X** = **a** dt + B d**W**, i.e., X, a, W are vectors and B is a matrix. This doesn't seem to be the case in the aRxiv paper and Wikipedia.

Comment: @SamD97 Look again more closely, you will find that only the case of a scalar Brownian motion is discussed extensively, the multidimensional case is only mentioned as outlook, requiring the computation of non-trivial interaction integrals of the components.